# How to check a token (CSRF) on controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, csrf

There is some option on Laravel that we allow Laravel to create a token and test it on server side to pull up CSRF attacks.

I found [this](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#csrf-protection) on Laravel website, But didn't say how to check from Controller that is an attack or from a native and real page.

**How to check the token (CSRF) on controller?**

Comment: Very important for this question: Are you using Laravel 5 or 4?

Comment: @lukasgeiter Thank you, I am using Laravel 4.2 but I am going to switch to 5 when the project finished

Comment: @lukasgeiter What is the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Assuming you use laravel 4.x:**

You don't need to check this in your controller. defining the `before` parameter tells laravel to check this automaticly.

```
Route::post('profile', array('before' => 'csrf', function(){ 
    /* CSRF validated! */  
}));
```

If you want to do something when the token is incorrect, you can change the filter in `app/filters.php`. This one:

```
Route::filter('csrf', function()
{
    if (Session::token() != Input::get('_token'))
    {
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
});
```

Comment: So good answer, and what about Laravel 4 and 5, witch one is diffrent

Comment: I mean this answer is for Laravel 4 or 5?

Comment: This answer is for Laravel 4

Answer (score 9):

#### Answer for Laravel 5

In Laravel 5 *middleware* replaces filters. This is also true for CSRF. The middleware is enabled by default and is handled in `App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken`.

It can be disabled by removing `App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken` in `App\Http\Kernel`. And if moved to `$routeMiddleware`...

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
    'auth.basic' => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',
    'guest' => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated',
    'csrf' => 'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
];
```

... it can be used conditionally by adding it to a route:

```
Route::post('foo', ['middleware' => 'csrf', 'uses' => 'BarController@foo']);
```

Or in the controllers constructor:

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware('csrf');
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for answering and spending your time. Accurately both answers are right (I think and I don't know which one should I accept). Thanks anyway

Comment: You're welcome. Just leave the other answer accepted since you are using Laravel 4. I just added this answer since you asked for the difference and it's not really something easily explained in a short comment ;)