# Check CSRF-Token in Laravel v. 5+

Tags: laravel, routes, csrf, verify

after some research for my project I stumbled upon this question: [How to check a token (CSRF) on controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28557408/how-to-check-a-token-csrf-on-controller)

The answer from Jerodev is exactly what I looked for except his answer is for Laravel 4.X
As I use the newest Laravel-Version I wanted to ask how to check/verify the @csrf token set up in the blade file while routing. Do I even have to do it or does Laravel check this automatically?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't have to do that, laravel does it, its the VerifyCsrfToken middleware, check app/Http/Kernel.php to see if the middleware is present in web group, it should be by default

Answer (score 0):

Laravel automatically generates a CSRF token for each active user session managed by the application so you dont have to do anything specially about it .

You can enable/disable it in kernel.php file located in :

```
app\Http\kernel.php
```

protected property called $middlewareGroups :

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
          ...
          ...
          ...
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
          ...
          ...
          ...

    ],

];
```

To disable it you have to comment this line out .

**Remember,csrf token is only works with post method and web requests .**